# How to fix menus that are not behaving when using CSS3 Media Queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am learning how to create responsive websites for a desktop, tablet, and mobile using CSS3 media queries. I created a fictional site to practice but I am having trouble with the menu-icon and the horizontal menu. In the desktop view, the menu is supposed to be horizontal and float to the right but instead, it's vertical. When I shrink the screen to the mobile dimensions the menu-icon shows up and the horizontal menu. I want the menu-icon to show on the mobile-view but it's not dropping the menu down. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

I have tried reversing the menu code in the media queries and my regular CSS code but the menus are still not working properly. I also for the display for the menu code I put none but all that did was have the all the menus disappear altogether. I have looked at numerous tutorials, but none of them helped me.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Abstract Alibi Agency</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Abstract Alibi Agency</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section class="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>We'll catch them in the act.</h2>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="main">
            <aside>
                <h3>Background Checks</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                </p>
            </aside>
        </section>

        <section>
            <aside>
                <h3>Investigate Infidilty</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                </p>
            </aside>
        </section>

        <section>
            <aside>
                <h3>Security</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                </p>
            </aside>
        </section>
        <footer>&copy; Abstract Alibi Agency 2018 - All Rights Reserved.</footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #999;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}

header {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    position: fixed;
}

h1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #00F;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
}

h3 {
    color: #00F;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
}

#menu-icon {
    background: url(../img/menu-icon.png);
    display: hidden;
    width: 50px;
    height: 42px;
    float: right;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}

a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

.hero {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../img/couple.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border-bottom: #000 2px solid;
    z-index: -1;
}

    .hero h2 {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 80px;
        color: #FFF;
        text-align: center;
    }

section .main aside {
    max-width: 425px;
    text-align: left;
}

aside {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

p {
    margin: 35px;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) { /* targets screens 640px and up */
    h3 {
        margin: 30px;
        color: #00F;
        text-align: left;
    }

    header {
        position: relative;
    }

    nav {
        float: right;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
    }

    #menu-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

    nav ul, nav:active ul {
        display: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #000;
        right: 5px;
        top: 65px;
        width: 10%;
    }

    nav:hover ul {
        display: block;
    }

    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    section .main aside {
        text-align: left;
    }

    aside {
        width: 33.3%;
        float: left;
    }

    footer {
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #999;
        text-align: center;
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

I want only the mobile version to show the menu-icon and have it drop down when clicked on and the tablet and desktop version to show the horizontal menu.

Comment: you are using fixed `width` on `ul` and `li`,` li` elements cant move, remove `ul` and `li` elements `width`, after that should be vertical, and add your removed `width` in `@media (max-width: 640px)` , after in mobile (in your define) should be horizontal and if not mobile vertical

Comment: did you look [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) before

Comment: Abdullah, I am confused because I do not have a width on my ul or li tag. The only thing I have a width on is the menu-icon and if I remove the width for that it disappears altogether. I also have one on this tag nav ul, nav:active ul but if I remove the width from that it just makes my menu wider vertically.

Answer (score 0):

set `nav ul` width 25% and remove `nav li` width and add last line current width `@media (max-width: 640px) { nav ul{ width:10%; } nav li{ width:100%} }`  like this

```
@media (min-width: 640px) {
    nav ul, nav:active ul {
        display: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #000;
        right: 5px;
        top: 65px;
        width: 25%;/* set to little more because Items can fit in horizontal */
    }

    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        /*width: 100%; remove li width than its should set auto 100% means 100% of parent(ul) and this makes a row(in block view)*/
        padding: 15px 15px;/*some padding for visibility*/
        margin: 0;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 640px) { 
        nav ul, nav:active ul {
        display: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #000;
        right: 5px;
        top: 65px;
        width: 10%;/*back to the you first width*/
    }

    nav li {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;/*open width for row to row view*/
        padding: 15px 0px;/*remove padding to normal*/
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

> mobile version to show the menu-icon and have it drop down when
>   clicked

Width some jquery

```
$('.menu-icon').click(function () {
    $("nav").toggleClass("nav-hidden-mobile");
});
```

and in your html `<nav>` to `<nav class="nav-hidden-mobile">`

and class css `@media (max-width: 640px) { .nav-hidden-mobile{ display:none; } }`

should be work, not tried this but upper css tried (*before write first comment*), its working

Comment: Abdullah, is there a way to do it without JavaScript? I am not good with it and this is making me more and more confused.